# Firebase Deploy get Parsing Error on "=>"

Tags: firebase, parsing-error

When I enter firebase deploy --only functions

The terminal has an issue with my code as:

amazon-clone-app\amazon-clone\functions\index.js
18:55  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token =>

This is my eslintrc.js file:

```
module.exports = { 
 root: true,
 env: {
  es6: true,
  node: true,
 },
 extends: [
  "eslint:recommended",
  "google",
  ], 
  rules: {
   quotes: ["error", "double"],
  },
};
```

And this is my index.js file at the function the terminal reports error:

```
app.post("/payments/create", async (request, response) => {
  const total = request.query.total;
  const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
     amount: total,
     currency: "usd",
  });

  response.status(201).send({
     clientSecret: paymentIntent.client_secret,
  });
});
```

Comment: im having the exact same problem even after i changed the firebase to a "BLAZE" account

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this will work for you as it did for myself. In the firebase.json file you have to change it to this. add the % to this "%$RESOURCE_DIR%. after that, firebase deploy --only functions worked.

```
 "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"%$RESOURCE_DIR%\" run lint"
    ],
```